# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade wired ethernet slow

Tags: 14.04, networking, broadcom, ethernet

I have upgraded to 14.04 and am experiencing slow wired ethernet connection.

Windows 7 pc wireless connection receives 8Mbs

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 1-2Mbs

Only started after upgrade.

Ethernet details:

Result of `lspci |grep net`

```
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

`ifconfig` output

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:72:9d:a6:d2  
          inet addr:192.168.0.8  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:72ff:fe9d:a6d2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30070 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32578630 (32.5 MB)  TX bytes:5027191 (5.0 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:478645 (478.6 KB)  TX bytes:478645 (478.6 KB)
```

ping -c10 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=31.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=33.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=31.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 time=36.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=48 time=35.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=48 time=33.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=48 time=29.9 ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.945/33.807/38.457/2.717 ms
```

wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip

```
--2014-10-20 21:11:31--  http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
Resolving speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com (speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com)... 208.43.102.250
Connecting to speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com (speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com)|208.43.102.250|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 524288000 (500M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

1% [=>                                                 ] 6,721,792    152KB/s  eta 34m 39s
```

Comment: Maybe it's just your internet connection that's slow. Do you have another device in the wired local network that you can use to benchmark network or internet speed?